# concatenating three fields using flow can someone please help

Tags: visual-workflow

Concatenating fields using flow, the formula expression is invalid for the below syntax, please help!

{!$Record.npe03__Donor_Name__c}&’ | ‘&TEXT{!$Record.npe03__Amount__c}&’ | ‘&TEXT{!$Record.AS_RG_Frequency__c}

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `TEXT()` function correctly.

Functions in formulas have a matched pair of parenthesis after the name of the function. The stuff inside (the "parameters", also called the "arguments") is what the function operates on.

Because I think this is also an issue you'll encounter eventually, functions also have a specific number (and order) of parameters that they take. So you can't just pass whatever you like into a function.

Fix this particular issue, you just need to add the open and close parenthesis. They should surround the references to your record's fields.
e.g.
instead of

```
TEXT{!$Record.npe03__Amount__c}
```

it needs to be

```
TEXT({!$Record.npe03__Amount__c})
```

Notice the parenthesis and their placement.
You'll need to do this for the `AS_RG_Frequency__c` reference too.